# How to update a variable of the Livewire component class when window focus event happens?

Tags: javascript, laravel, event-handling, laravel-livewire

### `MyLivewireComponent.php`

```php
<?php
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Person;

class MyLivewireComponent extends Component {
    public $persons;

    public function mount() {
        $this->persons = Person::all();
    }

    public function render() {
        return view('livewire.my-livewire-component');
    }
}
?>
```

When the browser's window got focused (`focus` event), I just want to update the contents and value of the `$persons` variable by **re-executing** the statement:

```php
$this->persons = Person::all();
```

So that it would get the new comprehensive list if ever there were additions to that collection.

This is because on my Blade...

### `my-livewire-component.blade.php`

```php
<select>
    @foreach($persons as $person)
    <option value="{{ $person->id }}">{{ $person->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This would ensure that the dropdown list is always updated once the user is back to the web application.

Which brings me back to my question. How to update a variable of the Livewire component class when window focus event happens?

Comment: PHP runs on the server ... so, not sure what you think you can do once the page is rendered in a browser

Comment: Okay, I'll add further details on the client-side environment.

Comment: i think you can add a focus event listener and call a function that will update the persons

Comment: and what version of livewire are you using ?

Comment: @KhayamKhan `v3.2.6` It seems doing it in `v2.*` is different as what I've understood.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by...

## `MyLivewireComponent.php`

```php
<?php
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Person;

class MyLivewireComponent extends Component {
    public $persons;

    public function mount() {
        $this->persons = Person::all();
    }

    public function render() {
        return view('livewire.my-livewire-component');
    }

    // Step 2 - Handle the event on the server-side
    #[On('updatePersons')]
    public function updatePersons() {
        $this->persons = Person::all();

        // Step 3 - Tell the client-side that there is an update
        $this->dispatch('personsUpdated');
    }

}
?>
```

## `my-livewire-component.blade.php`

```html
<div>

    <!-- Step 4 - Livewire will repaint it when it gets any update even though it wasn't specified which data were updated. Remember, that's how Livewire works -->
    <select>
        @foreach($persons as $person)
            <option value="{{ $person->id }}">{{ $person->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <!-- Step 1 - Listen to the focus event on the client-side -->
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
            Livewire.dispatch('updatePersons');
        });
    </script>

</div>
```

#### Versions

| Laravel | Livewire |
| --- | --- |
| `v10.35.0` | `v3.2.6` |

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AlpineJS you could use the x-on method. Using this handle you can fire events to execute Livewire methods that updates the Person list.

Example:

```
 <div x-on:blur="$dispatch('windowRefocused')">
```

[Livewire events](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events)

[AlpineJS x-on directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on)

[AlpineJS $dispatch magic](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/dispatch)